# Good Practice to have multiple instances of FirebaseDatabase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using `FirebaseDatabase` to get references to multiple different `DatabaseReference`s. I'm not sure if I  should be creating new `DatabaseReference` objects in every class I need to use them in, or if its better practice to make a static method or variable as way to get access from different classes.

An issue I'm encountering right now is I'm trying to populate a spinner from a database inside of a `DialogFragment`. I know how to do it in code but I'm just unsure about the "safe" way. It doesn't sound smart to create a reference to the database in every class.

I feel like I should make a class that just handles ALL the databasereferences and use getter methods to return the ones I need in the location I need. Any insight is appreciated.